# Android - App initialization slowed down after upgrading to FCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have recently upgraded my android app to FCM. Since then, the app initialization has slowed down. Its taking around 10-15 secs to show the splashscreen. Once initialized, the app is launching quickly upon further access. Also, the app has occupied ~15MB of data without any data saving from my end.

What could be the reason for this sluggishness and the data occupancy?

Comment: did you add all of the firebase libraries? did you remove the old version of gcm?

Comment: 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging' is the only dependency I have added. I also removed gcm dependency.

Comment: Have you tried to disable Instant Run feature?. It tends to add our apk size.

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thanks @isnotmenow. Instant run is the culprit here.

Comment: Great... Glad it work. :). should I make an answer or you make the answer then accept it ?

Comment: @isnotmenow : you should write down this as answer and rajeshT should accept it

Comment: @Shoshi: thanks for the suggestion. I've written the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve it by disabling **Instant Run** feature.
Instant Run need to add some files to work, so it tends to add our apk size.

Read More about [Instant Run](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html#instant-run).